# transformLaserScanToPointCloud usage problem

Tags: ros, laser-geometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I'm trying to de-rotate (project) LaserScan message using IMU.
p_base_frame_ is a string "base_stabilized".
scan is scan message. const sensor_msgs::LaserScan& scan.
sensor_msgs::PointCloud laser_point_cloud_;
tf::TransformListener tf_;

**Following is successful.**

tf::StampedTransform laserTransform;
tf_.lookupTransform(p_base_frame_,scan.header.frame_id, scan.header.stamp , laserTransform);

**But, following is not successful.**

transformLaserScanToPointCloud(p_base_frame_ , scan, laser_point_cloud_, tf_);

I don't know why. It basically find same transformation which is "base_stabilize" to "laser".
It exist. I confirmed by "rosrun tf view_frame".

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39978/transformlaserscantopointcloud-usage-problem./) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-27**:
Saying just '.. is not successful' makes it hard to infer what's going wrong. Please always post the complete error message and make sure you have a look at the support guidelines: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that in the *transformLaserScanToPointCloud* function a *lookupTransform* is called at time:

scan_in.header.stamp + ros::Duration ().fromSec (scan_in.ranges.size () * scan_in.time_increment)

My quick-fix solution was to call *waitForTransform* and include that added time before calling *transformLaserScanToPointCloud*.

Source: https://github.com/ros-perception/laser_geometry/blob/hydro-devel/src/laser_geometry.cpp

---

Originally posted by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) with karma: 438 on 2014-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0